# Изменение кодировки текста

Tags: c#

Имеется конструкция, которая производит чтение данных либо с текстового файла, либо с клавиатуры.
Возникло два вопроса:

1. Что надо изменить, чтобы при чтении из файла корректно читался русский язык?
2. Возможно, сможете помочь. Данная конструкция является частью программы по стеганографии. Если встраивается в аудио английский текст, то извлечение этого текста из аудио происходит корректно. Если же встраивается текст на русском языке, то происходит извлечение только лишь ровно половины спрятанного текста. В чем может быть проблема?

Код чтения с файла/с клавиатуры:

```
private Stream GetMessageStream()
{
    BinaryWriter messageWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
    if (rdoMsgFile.Checked)
    {
        //чтение из файла
        var fs = new FileStream(txtMsgFile.Text, FileMode.Open);
        int fileLength = (int)fs.Length;
        messageWriter.Write(fileLength);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, fileLength);
        messageWriter.Write(buffer);
        fs.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        // чтение с клавиатуры
        messageWriter.Write(txtMessage.Text.Length);
        messageWriter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text));
    }
    messageWriter.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return messageWriter.BaseStream;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Нет такого понятия — текстовый файл без кодировки. Текстовый файл обязательно имеет какую-то кодировку. Указывайте кодировку при открытии. Нет, надёжного метода *узнать* кодировку, не зная её, нет.
2. Вы пишете в `messageWriter` длину текста в символах, а потом кладёте туда байты. Вероятно, проблема в этом: длина в символах не равна длине в байтах.

---

Кстати, как-то слишком сложно работаете с файлом. Я бы на вашем месте просто использовал

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(txtMsgFile.Text);
messageWriter.Write(buffer.Length);
messageWriter.Write(buffer);
```

Но поскольку вам нужно перекодировать файл, скорее всего, корректнее будет так:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(txtMsgFile.Text, encoding); // <-- encoding важно
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

И вообще весь код выглядел бы тогда просто так:

```
string text = rdoMsgFile.Checked ?
    File.ReadAllText(txtMsgFile.Text, encoding) : txtMessage.Text;
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
messageWriter.Write(buffer.Length);
messageWriter.Write(buffer);
```

Comment: Второй вопрос решен.
Первый вопрос остался в силе. Описание проблемы: на вход подается стандартный .txt файл, который может содержать в себе любой текст (числа, буквы английские, русские и т.д.). Извлечение русского текста, который был встроен в аудио файл, происходит некорректно - выдается в ответе не текст, а набор символов неизвестной кодировки.
Ошибку методов кодирования/раскодирования можно исключить, так как кодирование/раскодирование сообщения, которое подается с клавиатуры, происходит корректно.
Можно ли как-то это исправить, применив какой-либо метод класса Encoding?

Comment: @Ivan52: То есть вы хотите сказать, что вы указали правильную кодировку текстового файла? Вангую, что вы этого не сделали.